# C# Read column from CSV file only if column name exists in list

Tags: c#, csv

I have a list of column headers that are read from a file into a List:

```
// Read column headers from text file
List<string> colHeads = new List<string>();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\DATA\\MLData\\colHeads.txt");
string[] spl = new string[100];

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    spl = line.Split('=');
    colHeads.Add(spl[0].Trim());
}
```

I would like to then read a CSV file but only read the columns that are in the list:

```
// Read CSV file
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\DATA\\MLData\hist.csv");
string[] spl = new string[500];

foreach (string line in lines)
{
        spl = line.Split(',');
        var rec = new Record()
        {
            Name = spl[1],
            ident = float.Parse(spl[4], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
            location = float.Parse(spl[5], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
            ...
            ...
        };
}
```

Example of colHeads.txt....

```
Name
ident
location
...
```

Example of hist.csv...

```
Name,yob,ident,level,location,score1
John B,1981,23,3,GB,54
```

There are more columns in hist.csv than colHeads.txt so I need a way to read the csv file by column name rather than column number, ignoring the columns that are not in the list. The variables I'm assigning to match the column names exactly.

Comment: If Record is a class or structure that have  field or property name as same as excel columns name , you can using reflection for assigning it, dynamically

Comment: Did you heard about libraries like [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/)? You can work with lines as objects and do a lot of staff.

Comment: Does the first line of the CSV file contain headers?

Comment: Show us colHeads.txt and couple lines of hist.csv.

Comment: Bijan, yes it's a class and the names do match, how would I use 'Reflection'? Alexander: Yes it does, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `colHeads` contains a list of header names, you can try something like this.

```
location = colHeads.Contains("location") ? float.Parse(spl[5], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat) : 0
```

If the set of available columns are always the same, and you just want to change the columns you read, this will probably work fine for basic use.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, the data in the csv file is not the same, it has lot's of columns  dont use so I'd need to match the column name to the variable name (they exactly the same).

Comment: @user2096512 I adjusted my assumption. I meant to say that it assumes that the set of available columns will always be the same, but the rows will be different. Or, are you saying that each CSV file will always have a different set of columns?

Comment: I've done it now using csvHelper, it has the functionality to match class variables to headers automatically: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records/

Comment: @user2096512 Awesome. CSVHelper is a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
var colHeads = File.ReadLines("colHeads.txt").ToHashSet();
var lines = File.ReadLines("hist.csv");
var headers = lines.First().Split(',');
var indexes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var records = new List<Record>();

for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
{
    indexes[headers[i]] = colHeads.Contains(headers[i]) ? i : -1;
}

int nameIndex = indexes[nameof(Record.Name)];
int identIndex = indexes[nameof(Record.ident)];
int locationIndex = indexes[nameof(Record.location)];
//...

foreach (var line in lines.Skip(1))
{
    var values = line.Split(',');
    var record = new Record();
    records.Add(record);

    if (nameIndex >= 0) record.Name = values[nameIndex];
    if (identIndex >= 0) record.ident = float.Parse(values[identIndex]);
    if (locationIndex >= 0) record.location = values[locationIndex];
    //...
}
```

First we read the header from the hist.csv file and assign indexes.
Next, using these indexes, we set the properties of the record.